# How to sniff HTTPS traffic of apps that ignore system proxy setting?

Tags: sniffing, https-protocol

I want to sniff and decrypt HTTPS traffic of apps that ignore system proxy setting on macOS. If I understand correctly, common tools like Charles cannot help. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can install an extra CA, it shouldn't be a problem. Mitmproxy has documentation on how to set up transparent intercepting.

http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/transparent.html

Comment: Sorry, but what is CA?

Comment: @an0 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority

Answer (score 0):

Get mitmproxy running. Set up that as the proxy for HTTP and HTTPS. Then load a web browser and to go http://mitm.it and download the newly generated certificate. Double click the file you just downloaded. Then within Keychains you'll want to tell the system to trust that cert ("always trust"). 
Then what I typically do is set the Router to the IP of the host running mitmproxy. Run mitmproxy with the transparent settings (-T) I believe.